# Error with MongoDB, Can't locate object method

Tags: perl, mongodb

I want to access at my database in this way:

```
my $db = MongoDB::Connection->new or die( "erreur de connection" );
db = $db->chasseur_de_tete;
```

and I get this error:

Can't locate object method "chasseur_de_tete" via package "MongoDB::Connection" at ../AbstractExtract.pm line 25.

I don't understand why, after search for similar cases, I saw that problemme could be caused by not updating modules (like DateTime). but even after update, I get the same error.

Have you some idea please ? Thanks

Comment: What is `chasseur_de_tete`? It's not a method of MongoDB::Connection module.

Comment: It's a headhunter! ;)

Comment: yes, it's the name of my database =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred method is to use the [MongoClient](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB%3a%3aMongoClient) class and accessors to databases and collections are not built in, they require separate methods to retrieve.

```
use MongoDB;

my $client     = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
my $database   = $client->get_database( 'chasseur_de_tete' );
my $collection = $database->get_collection( 'mycollection' );
```

Also the same code is equivalent for the `$client` connection:

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new();
```

Which assumes the default values for the connection.

Comment: @user2323174 Just a friendly reminder to accept your answers.